# How to redirect to another webpage from Google Apps Script Gadget?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sites

I'm building a web application in Google Sites. Currently, I have two forms, the first one loads a Spreadsheet and displays it as a table, then when you select a row from the table, the script calls another Web App with a GET request and with a few parameters (as `?rowIndex=X&columnIndex=..`).

This is working fine if I deploy the first form as a Web App. But if I insert the first script as a "Google Apps Script Gadget" in my Google Sites webpage it seems that is embedded as an Iframe that cannot redirect to other webpages/scripts (it just shows a blank iframe).

Is there any way to solve this without merging both scripts in one?

For the redirect, I'm using javascript in the HTML form.

```
windows.location="secondScriptUrl"+"?parameters..."
```

and the second script just generates the HTML from the `doGet` function

```
function doGet(e) {
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}
```

Comment: why are 2 web apps being used out of curiosity?

Comment: Because one is used to show information stored in a Spreadsheet and when you select one row of data, the data is sent to the other Web App that let you edit and manage the information.

Comment: HtmlService doesn't allow to acces different html files in the same project, you have to make a GET request again and I tought that It was better to have separate projects.

Comment: right, it's a single-page app but you can certainly store the the needed html for other page views client side or write the change logic in JS.  Running a `google.script.run.yourFunctionToGetHtmlContent()`. is going to be faster than a  whole browser window refresh too.  That `.top` was a missing piece for me on redirects though.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it adding:

```
<base target="_top">
```

to the html code and changing the javascript redirect:

```
window.top.location.href = url;
```

Comment: From today, I noticed that it is not working anymore.